# Bootstrap tooltip with input type range

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip with a range input. I can see the value getting updated but the tooltip as such is not visible on the screen.
This makes me wonder if tooltip is compatible with input type="range". Or am I missing something? Here's what I am doing:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1000"
    ng-change="update()"
    ng-mouseenter="setPosition($event)"
    ng-mouseleave="resetPosition()"
    ng-model="position"
    uib-tooltip="{{seekValue}}"
    uib-tooltip-placement="top" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is compatible.

My guess is that your `{{seekValue}}` is empty, if you will change it to the ngModel variable you should see a changing value

```
<input type="range"
  min="0" max="1000" 
  ng-change="update()" 
  ng-mouseenter="setPosition($event)" 
  ng-mouseleave="resetPosition()" 
  ng-model="scaleValue" 
  uib-tooltip="{{scaleValue}}" 
  uib-tooltip-placement="top"/>
```

[Demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lgECVatcjayrq38VqZ67?p=preview)

Comment: You are right. Thanks for pointing it out. Looks like the tooltip is bound to ng-model.